# How can I prove that: of A and ( not A or B) is equivalent to A and B

Tags: logic

How can I prove that:

```
A and ( not A or B) is equivalent to A and B
```

It is easy to show with a truth table how can I do only using the properties of the logical operators (e.g association, distribution, etc...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Conjunction distributes over disjunction.

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Yes I can thanks a lot!